# How to remove cookies from a headless browser provided by HtmlUnit in Java?

Tags: java, browser, cookies, htmlunit, headless

I am using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) headless browser to access websites.

Can the cookies sent by those websites store on my computer when I use that headless browser?

If yes, then what's the location where these cookies get saved and how can I remove it through HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**HtmlUnit.removeCookie()**](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.html#removeCookie%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie%29). Typically the Cookies in HtmlUnit are created in memory and not serialized to disk.

Comment: Could you please tell me the lifetime of those cookies in the memory? When they get deleted? Can the webserver detects those cookies which are in memory? How can I delete those cookies?

Comment: Since they're in memory, they'll terminate as soon as your HtmlUnit session does. They'll also get deleted if you explicitly call `removeCookie()`. The web server doesn't really "detect" cookies -- instead it asks the user agent if any cookies are stored, and HtmlUnit will respond accordingly.

Comment: So, if the cookies are in memory then Will HtmlUnit respond the server with cookies? When the HtmlUnit session terminates? Will it terminate when i call webclient.closeWindow()?
As acc. to the HtmlUnit docs, WebClient represents a browser, so Is it represent a mutiple-windows browser (like IE7 in which we can open multiple tabs) or represen a single-window browser?

Comment: If it represents a multiple-window browser, then does the HttpSession is maintained accross multiple windows of that webclient like real browsers?

Comment: You might want to ask a separate StackOverflow question to provide a better forum for these detailed follow-ups you're asking.

Comment: Ok. I have posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081260/htmlunit-doubts-regarding-cookies-and-windows

Could you please look at that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

> webClient.getCookieManager().clearCookies();