# HtmlUnit doubts regarding cookies and windows

Tags: java, browser, cookies, htmlunit

If the HtmlUnit stores cookies in memory then Will HtmlUnit respond the server with cookies?

When the HtmlUnit session terminates? Will it terminate when i call webclient.closeWindow()?

As acc. to the HtmlUnit docs, WebClient represents a browser, so Is it represent a mutiple-windows browser (like IE7 in which we can open multiple tabs) or represen a single-window browser?

If it represents a multiple-window browser, then does the HttpSession is maintained accross multiple windows of that webclient like real browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but some hints.

> If the HtmlUnit stores cookies in memory then Will HtmlUnit respond the server with cookies?

HtmlUnit's cookie policy is to be browser-compatible so I would expect it to do so.

> When the HtmlUnit session terminates? Will it terminate when i call webclient.closeWindow()?

I'm not sure about this one. Did you try to test or debug this? Did you look at the source code? Actually, I wonder what should be the expected behavior here.

> As acc. to the HtmlUnit docs, WebClient represents a browser, so does it represent a mutiple-windows browser (like IE7 in which we can open multiple tabs) or a single-window browser?

I consider that `WebClient` represents a single tabbed browser.

> If it represents a multiple-window browser, then does the HttpSession is maintained accross multiple windows of that webclient like real browsers?

Note that this behavior is not consistent between browsers and between browser versions: IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox, Chrome, they all behave (more or less) differently (see [Cookies in Firefox and Internet Explorer](http://insidethemachine.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/cookies-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer/), or [Browsers, processes, cookies and session state](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2007/11/06/Browsers_2C00_-processes_2C00_-cookies-and-session-state.aspx), or [Session Cookies, sessionStorage, and IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx)). So I wouldn't consider that there is a general rule with "real" browsers.

Actually, I think that your best weapons are the source code and your debugger. These questions would be easy to verify IMO.

Comment: +1 Could you please look at the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131049/problem-in-htmlunit-api-for-java-headless-browser